# How do you get a form to never go to full screen when double clicked in C#

Tags: c#

I have a C# form that always goes to the full screen mode when i double click it.
The form has no border and moves.

Comment: Are you using `WinForms` or `WPF`?

Comment: That's impossible unless some code is written in the form that performs this. Double-click only in the caption of the form maximizes the form. Inspect the code. The problem is in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the maximum width & height of the form. You use the `MaximumSize` property of the form.

`this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 500);`

or `this.MaximumSize = this.Size;`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.maximumsize.aspx